# Invalid Datatypes When Creating Table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a table called Movie_Stars. It needs to include 5 columns:
Movie_Number (numeric) that uniquely defines each movie, Movie_Title varying character (30), Year_Released date and time (required), First_Name varying character (20), and Last_Name varying character (20). Here's the code I wrote:

```
create table Movie_Stars
         (Movie_Number number unique,
          Movie_Title varchar2 (30),
          Year_Released datetime not null,
          First_Name varchar2 (15),
          Last_Name varchar2 (15));
```

However, the error "invalid datatypes" occurred when I run the script. How do I fix this?

Comment: Evidently one or more of your data type specifications is incorrect. Have you looked at what the valid syntax and data types are in Oracle?

Comment: Try to run it in SQLPlus; it will easily say you what's wrong

Comment: @Aleksej, I don't have SQL Plus :(

Comment: If you want to identify the incorrect data type first (so you don't have to check the documentation for all of them), comment out one column at a time. When there's no error message, that will tell you that the column you just commented is the one with the error. (Then drop the table so you can re-create it with all the columns after you fix the error.)

Comment: @tim - It is almost certain you "have" SQL\*Plus, you just don't know where it is. Ask your DBA or a more experienced user where to "find" it, it will take them less than 20 seconds, I promise! And it will help you a lot to play with it a little and to know where it is when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, only an hint:

```
SQL> create table Movie_Stars
  2           (Movie_Number number unique,
  3            Movie_Title varchar2 (30),
  4            Year_Released datetime not null,
  5            First_Name varchar2 (15),
  6            Last_Name varchar2 (15));
          Year_Released datetime not null,
                        *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Comment: So datetime is not a valid datatype? But I need to fill in both dates and times into the columns.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Movie_Stars
  2           (Movie_Number number unique,
  3            Movie_Title varchar2 (30),
  4            Year_Released **date** not null,
  5            First_Name varchar2 (15),
  6            Last_Name varchar2 (15));
```

Comment: **date** shows an invalid datatype error. Right now I decided to just stick with date instead.